# Akka Named Resource Serial Execution

Tags: scala, akka

I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish the following.  My Akka application, which will be running as a cluster, will be persisting to a backend web service.  Each resource I'm persisting is named.  For example: A, B, C

There will be a queue of changes for each resource, and I'm looking for an idea on how I can have a configuration which allows me to control the following:

- Maximum number of REST calls in progress at any point in time (overall concurrency)
- Ensure that only one REST request for each named resource is in progress
- It's fine for concurrent requests, as long as they are not for the same resource
- The named resources are dynamic, based on records in a database

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My vision is next:

You need to have some kind of supervisor actor which maintains some state. On each request to this supervisor you check wheather you have this resource been currently processing. If yes, then you should store this request to some storage/queue. If no, spawn new actor and put this actor and the resource to the mentioned state. On completion, remove the actor and resource from the state. I strongly recommend you to have storage/queue to temporarily save request to supervisor actor. In such case you protect yourself from overwhelming the system. To guarantee overall concurrency requirement you may make internal state of supervisor bounded and if the size exceeds you store request to storage/queue.

Of course you need some mechanism of polling this queue and make requests to supervisor